# What is "composite" in the Android Composite ADB Interface?

Tags: usb-drivers

What's the difference between the Android ADB Interface and the Android *Composite* ADB Interface?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Android Composite interface is higher level interface that includes Android ADB (Android Debug Bridge) interface, Android MTP (Media Transfer Protocol), PTP (Picture Transfer Protocol), Mass Storage Protocol etc. depending on what you need to do with connected device and on type of device as well.